# How to join tables randomly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have two tables (`TableA` and `TableB`)
`TableA` has 10 rows and `TableB` have 50 rows.
I want each row in TableA to be joined with `X` number of rows from `TableB` randomly.

For example if `TableA` has rows `(a,b,c)` and `TableB` have rows `(p,q,r,s,t,u)` and `X=2` ,then expected result is:

```
a-p
a-u
b-r
b-t
c-s
c-q
```

This joining should be random.

Comment: I am not a mysql expert, so anyone can please clarify the answer in link above

Comment: Your last edit changes your question too significantly. Now your post is inconsistent and may be closed from this reason. You should not change question in a way that invalidates valid answer. I advise you to revert above post to previous version and ask new question referring to above one.

Comment: Done + marked your answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RAND()` :

```
select x,y from 
(
    select t.*,  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank from
    (
        select tablea.x, tableb.y, rand() r
        from tablea cross join tableb
         order by x, r
    ) t, (SELECT @rownum := -1) r
) tr
where tr.rank%(select count(y) from tableB)<2
```

In above query I am joining every element from `tableA` with every element of `tableB`. For every such row `RAND()` value is computed. Then such table is sorted by this rank for every value from `tableA`. Then I only need select first `X` rows for every value.

Number `2` in this query is your `X`.

You can see it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cbc9/31)

**EDIT:**

I have found a solution where `tableB` elements are not repeated:

```
select ta.x, tb.y from 
(
   select y, @rownumB := @rownumB + 1 as rnB 
   from  
   (select y, rand() as r from tableB order by r) t, (SELECT @rownumB := -1) rownB
) tb,
(
   select x, @rownumA := @rownumA + 1 as rnA
   from tableA, (SELECT @rownumA := -1) rownA
) ta
where tb.rnB%5=ta.rnA
order by ta.x;
```

Above query does:

- shuffles `tableB`
- assigns row numbers `rnB` (0..14) to rows of shuffled `tableB`
- assigns row numbers `rnA` (0..4) to rows of `tableA`
- joins 'tableB' with `tableA` using `%` operator
- `tableB` has 15 elements. So `rnB%5` will give numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4). These numbers are joined with `rnA`. So every row from `tableA` is joined with 3 rows of `tableB`

See this in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3600e6/12)

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry for so late response.The result which is obtained from the code you sujsted is giving duplicate entries from tableB after joining.But values form tableB should not be repeated , as you can see in my example above

Comment: @MohdQasim Hi Mohd. I corrected my solution. I think that now it gives desired result. Can you evaluate it?

Comment: Its almost done, but I think I have to tell you the complete problem.I am going to edit my question again